# Dom traversal return nil even though the test condition seems to be true

Tags: html, list, pcase, recursion, plists

The purpose of the traversal this time is to be able to visit each node, if there is a specific attribute inside that node, it should return true, add that node to the list and proceed on the next recursion as the following code:

```lisp
(defun pick-tag (x)
  (let ((text-list '()) (node (dom-node x)))
    (pcase (dom-tag node)
      ;; ((pred stringp) (dom-tag node))
      ;; ('comment '())
      ((pred consp) (when (assoc 'data-table (dom-attributes node))
                        (push (dom-text node) text-list))) ;;I was expecting this to be true.
      (_
       (mapconcat #'pick-tag (dom-children node) "")))))
```

From the above code, per my conviction, for `data-table` being a symbol inside the node's attribute should return true. but after evaluating the code below, I only obtain a nil result.

```lisp
(defun macro-listify (tag-entries)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert tag-entries)
    (let* ((mytags (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max))))
      (text-tag (car (dom-by-tag mytags 'body))))))

(let ((mytree "<html>
     <head>
         <title>Demo: Gradient Slide</title>
     </head>
     <link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
     <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"dist/build.css\">
     <body>
         <header data-table=\"testtable\">
             <h1 data-field=\"testfield\">Skeleton Screen</h1>
             <h1 data-field=\"newfield\">Skeleton Screen</h1>
         </header>
         <div class=\"wrap\"> Sample Text <p class=\"format\" data-attribute=\"somethingsomething\">Welcome to this page</p>
             <div class=\"flex-grid generic-card\">
                 <!-- ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIMATE -->
                 <div class=\"card loading\">Text </div>
                 <!-- ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIMATE 
                   this multiline comment 
                   -->
                <div class=\"card loading\"></div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </body>
 </html>"))
  (macro-listify mytree))
```